# Unable to Update Staging record in Oracle , sql developer

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

Below is my query that I have written to update the given field but its throwing cannot update char to null error.

```
UPDATE PS_H_BN_MCR_STG A SET A.H_BN_INITIAL_PARTN=(SELECT NVL(D.NAME_INITIALS,' ') 
  FROM PS_DEP_BEN_NAME D 
  WHERE D.EMPLID=A.EMPLID 
  AND D.DEPENDENT_BENEF=01 
  AND D.EFFDT=( 
SELECT MAX(D1.EFFDT) 
 FROM PS_DEP_BEN_NAME D1 
WHERE D1.EMPLID=D.EMPLID 
  AND D1.DEPENDENT_BENEF=D.DEPENDENT_BENEF 
  AND D1.EFFDT<=SYSDATE)) WHERE A.MARITAL_STATUS IN (1,6,7);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check your solution into this way:(1) first change the column(H_BN_INITIAL_PARTN) now allow null  by below query.then run query

```html
alter table       PS_H_BN_MCR_STG 
modify (H_BN_INITIAL_PARTN NULL);
```

(2)

Comment: Thanks for the reply
I have used %coalesce and its working now